# VB.net or Javascript to check connection in LAN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, lan

Good day everyone,

Currently I am having a web application run on my server. One of its function was displaying 2 pages which is: "Slideshow of Pictures" >> "Bar Graph"
means that from slideshow.aspx to graph.aspx in loop.. This 2 pages always run in loop, then repeat.

The real problem that I am having right now was whenever the connection is lost, on the point where page are suppose to redirect to next pages.. it will show the "No connection error message" or "Connection has timed out" and it will remain there.. Then I will need to refresh/reload the page to make it work again.

Is there is any ways that I could check on the connection availability first before the page is automatically redirecting to next page. If the connection was unavailable then it should remain there until the connection is available or in the other word i can say pause until connection is available...
After the connection is available, then it should work as normal, which redirecting to next page.

Is there is any ways that I could achieve this? Using javascript or VB.net if possible.. so that user wont need to go and refresh on every Smart TV browser whenever there is connection lost.. I had been trying for like weeks already but none actually work...I really need help on this one..thank you

Again..I am so sorry for my bad English..Hope that my explanation were quite clear and is understandable... Below is the code in javascript that i used to redirect to next page, which is graph page.. I need to add a code to check on connection status before redirecting...

```
function myHandler(e) {
        if (params[1] == "slide=1") {
            window.location.href = '../QC/BigMonitorRealTime?operationOID=50';
        }
        else if (params[1] == "slide=2") {
            window.location.href = '../QC/BigMonitorRealTime?operationOID=60';
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = '../QC/BigMonitorRealTime';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd go with javascript ... the client needs to know, the server does not

Comment: @JaromandaX ty for replying.. if it was javascript..how can this be done?

Comment: Could you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

Comment: @GaganDeep thanks for replying..by the way..how can this be done? I am so sorry because I am totally new with this javascript things.. :( I hope that u could give some advice to me

Comment: which smart TV are u using

Comment: @Vikas Sorry for the delay in replying... It was Samsung smart TV sir